# How to highlight a gridview row if some object value is greater than another?

Tags: wpf, data-binding

would like to know how to highlight a gridview row if some object value is greater than another ? (Consider the gridview to be bind to an observablecollection)

Thanks.

Comment: Easiest done in the model. Your item level class should contain a property which stores the result of whatever comparison you are doing and then based on this result use the converter and change the background of the item's row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to implement a converter to do a > comparison but this shows a highlight

```
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsParent}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gainsboro"  />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Answer (score 4):

Put a property on the class of the items in your observable collection that will get set to true/false based on the comparison you need.  Then you should be able to bind to this property in a DataTrigger for a Style on the DataGrid's ItemContainerStyle.

Try this...

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding YourObservableCollection}" >
        <DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding YourShouldHighlightProperty}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Control.Background" Value="Red"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: The question was for "gridview" not DataGrid.   I don't think  <DataGrid.ItemContainerSyle> is compatible with gridview.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code.It wored for me.

```
 private void DataGrid_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (loadtodatagrid item in gridview.ItemsSource)
                {
                    var row = gridview.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as DataGridRow;
                    if (item.item1== item.item2)
                    {
                        row.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // row.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ep)
            {
                //do nothing....
            }
```

LoadingRow="DataGrid_LoadingRow" to datagrid in WPF